# Как перейти на другую страницу сайта после авторизации?

Tags: node.js

На сервере(NodeJS/ExpressJS) происходит авторизация, посредством заголовка Authorisation, если она прошла успешно, клиенту отправляется 201 статус с сообщением "Ok". После получения этого статуса на клиенте необходимо перейти на основную страницу. При location.href - заголовок авторизации не передается, поэтому на клиент прилетает опять форма авторизации(используется middleware). Если на сервере использовать response.redirect("/main") то прилетает страница на клиент в виде текста(await response.text()).
Подскажите как правильно редирект произвести на главную страницу после авторизации, при условии что токен передается в заголовке.

Comment: Покажите это все кодом. Редирет может быть, если вы обращаетесь по заданному URL, а если вы осуществляете запросы(fetch), то переадресовываются сами запросы, а не страница браузера.

Comment: На сервере: app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers.authorisation)
    if(req.headers.authorisation === undefined) {
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/page', 'auth.html'));
    }
    
    next();
})

Comment: Обновите вопрос и код добавьте туда. Как отправляете с клиента запрос, какой роут на сервере его обрабатывает и т.д.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выполнить редирект на другую страницу сайта после авторизации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1541941/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)