# Как выполнить редирект на другую страницу сайта после авторизации?

Tags: node.js

На сервере(NodeJS/ExpressJS) происходит авторизация, посредством заголовка Authorisation, если она прошла успешно, клиенту отправляется 201 статус с сообщением "Ok". После получения этого статуса на клиенте необходимо перейти на основную страницу. При location.href - заголовок авторизации не передается, поэтому на клиент прилетает опять форма авторизации(используется middleware). Если на сервере использовать response.redirect("/main") то прилетает страница на клиент в виде текста(await response.text()). Подскажите как правильно редирект произвести на главную страницу после авторизации, при условии что токен передается в заголовке.

На сервере:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.headers.authorisation)
        if(req.headers.authorisation === undefined) {
            return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/page', 'auth.html'));
        }
        
        next();
    })

    app.get("/login", function(req, res, next){
        if (isValidPassword(user.password, req.body.password)) {
            const token = uuidv4.v4();
            await db.updateToken(token, user.id);
            
            res.set("Authorisation", token);
            //res.header("Authorisation", token);
            
            // res.status(201).send({message: "Ok"});

            res.redirect('/');
          }
    });

    app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/page', 'index.html'));
    });
```

На клиенте:

```
let response = await fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorisation': null
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({password: password.value, email: login.value})
    });
```

Comment: Шлешь `POST`... Обрабатываешь только `get`.

Answer (score 0):

**res.redirect('/')** Перенаправит ваш fetch запрос по адресу, который был прислан в ответе, далее пойдет такой же запрос по переданному адресу.

Однако это не приведет к переадресации URL в браузере.

Отдайте обычный ответ браузеру, а уже в браузере проверяйте условия и выполняйте переадресацию:

В качестве примера:
На сервере

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res, next){
  if (isValidPassword(user.password, req.body.password)) {
    const token = uuidv4.v4();
    await db.updateToken(token, user.id);

    res.writeHead(308, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    res.write(JSON.stringify({
      Authorisation: token,
      url: '/'
    }));
    res.end();
  }
});
```

На клиенте:

```
fetch('/login', {
  method: 'POST',
})
  .then(async resp => {
    if (resp.status === 308) {
      const body = await resp.json();
      if (body.Authorisation) {
        location.href = body.url;
      }
    }

  })
```

Comment: Так при переходе на другой url (location.href = body.url;) заголовок Authorisation теряется, и на сервере я опять становлюсь не авторизованным, или я не так как то понял?

Comment: Вы можете сохранить авторизацию где то в куках. и при переходе на следующую страницу передавать его любым удобным способом. В любом случае, для сервера это новый запрос и он о предыдущем ничего не знает, это задача клиента, говорить, что он уже авторизован. На сервере вы можете отдельно проверять ключи авторизации, выданные пользователям. Я вот, не смог выдернуть из ответа хедер с тегом Authorisation

Comment: С куками да, так сработает, они всегда связаны с запросом, даже если через location.href.